# Component not render the newest value?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm getting used to with redux. My problem is the itemList correctly render the latest value but the value of Checkbox which is from hook state not get the latest value. It should be checked for all item list but it is not. Although I console.log the values in the map func, it still get the latest values and the find func is correct.

```
 
export default function Component(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { itemList } = useSelector((state) => state.AllCourses);

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    all: true,
    items: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      someActions.getItemList(payload)
    ); //this will get latest itemList
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (itemList.length) {
      const newValues = {
        all: true,
        items: itemList.map((item) => ({
          select: true,
          id: item.id,
        })),
      };
      setValues(newValues);
    }
  }, [itemList]);

  return (
      <Box ml={4}>
        { itemList?.map((item) => {
            return (
              <Box key={item.id}>
                <Checkbox
                  name={item.name}
                  value={values?.items?.find((itemVal) => item.id === itemVal.id)?.select}
                />
              </Box>
            );
          })}
      </Box>
  );
}
```

`

Tried several solutions but still not correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using Material UI. For checkbox component you need to set the checked prop.

```
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';

const label = { inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'Checkbox demo' } };

export default function Checkboxes() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox {...label} defaultChecked />
      <Checkbox {...label} />
      <Checkbox {...label} disabled />
      <Checkbox {...label} disabled checked />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you use html input tag with type checkbox, then again you have to set the checked attribute accordingly see below.

```
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" checked>
```

And lastly, you don't need a local state in your example and you can remove

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    all: true,
    items: []
  });
```

and

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (itemList.length) {
      const newValues = {
        all: true,
        items: itemList.map((item) => ({
          select: true,
          id: item.id,
        })),
      };
      setValues(newValues);
    }
  }, [itemList]);
```

and replace with

```
const values = {
        all: true,
        items: itemList && itemList.length ? itemList.map((item) => ({
          select: true,
          id: item.id,
        })) : [],
      };
```